# automatization of vm configuring

Tags: vmware

Есть ли возможность повесить скрипт на событие power-on в VMware? И как это делается? Сейчас я использую мапирование диска целевой машины на хостовую, и вручную переписываю файлы. Хотелось бы автоматизировать этот процесс.

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопрос на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Comment: Перевод: Есть ли возможность повесить скрипт на событие power-on в VMware? И как это делается?
Сейчас я использую мапирование диска целевой машины на хостовую, и вручную переписываю файлы. Хотелось бы автоматизировать этот процесс.

Comment: Нажмите под вопросом кнопку "править", и вставьте текст непосредственно в вопрос, а не в комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

```
file: MyCopy.bat

copy D:\Photos\2017\*.jpg E:\New\

Result:
All files with ending "jpg" (duplicate) D:\Photos\2017 => E:\New\
```

Comment: Копирование файлов - это понятно. Больше интересует, как автоматически мапировать диск виртуальной машины при power-on.

Answer (score 0):

у VMware нет такой возможности автоматически выполнить что-либо при собитии. Но вы сможете это делать, если вы уже знаете имя машины или же vmMor машины, только скрипт должен крутится и все время чекать состояние машины.

Было бы лучше сделать снапшот на машине с нужными дисками или файлами, или же на самой гостевой машине настроить автозапуск скрипта определнного.

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно обновлять загрузочный efi раздел диска. Загрузчик там выполняется соответственно до загрузки ОС. А как, вообще писать скрипт для vmware, что почитать?

Comment: а в чем проблема? добавьте диск, обновите анстройки загрузки и создайте снапшот. на крйный случай, что я не рекомендую. можно подложить нужный *.nvram файл и тогда ВМ загрузится оттуда, откуда скажете

Comment: Мне нужно при каждом запуске записывать новые версии файлов на раздел. Может, я что-то не понимаю, но как снапшот мне поможет это сделать?

Comment: тогда я не так понял вопрос. тогда причем тут загрузочный диск и efi ?

Comment: Я тестирую свой загрузчик ос. В целях безопасности - делаю это на vm. Он лежит в системном разделе gpt диска(целевой машины). Бинарник собирается на хостовой. Мне чтобы каждый раз после правок не делать длинную ручную процедуру по мапированию диска целевой машины и последующей записи бинарников загрузчика, захотелось узнать, можно ли это дело автоматизировать. Грубо говоря, есть ли вообще возможность писать скрипты для vm?

Comment: все есть. [ссылка](https://code.vmware.com/tool/vsphere-cli/6.5) а лучше подключить в PowerShell `Add-PSSnapin VMWare.VimAutomation.Core` и работать с Vmware

Comment: ткните пожалуйста в команду vSphere, которая запишет файлы на таргет?

Comment: @Alexey [вот](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/windowstoolkit/wintk40u1/html/Copy-VMGuestFile.html) `Copy-VMGuestFile -Source $source -Destination $target  -vm $VM -LocalToGuest -GuestUser $guser -GuestPassword $gpass -Force:$true -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue`